# VS2015 - Couldn't input command in JavaScript in Cordova project

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2015, taco, tools-for-apache-cordova

I was able to start debugging in VS2015(Tools for Apache Cordova) project, but didn't know what happened VS2015 stop to let me debug step by step. See as below, when I want to give command in JavaScript Console window > window.location.reload(), it give me "You are not currently attached to a supported page or app", does anyone have the same issue before?

[image: Link]

**Update: 20161220. List of devices attached.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> but didn't know what happened VS2015 stop to let me debug step by step. See as below, when I want to give command in JavaScript Console window > window.location.reload(), it give me "You are not currently attached to a supported page or app", does anyone have the same issue before?

I guess you are currently using Ripple Emulator. If you want to debug your app in Ripple emulator, just refresh the page of your web browser and don't use `window.location.reload()`.

Notes: Ripple can only emulate web contents. For running native plugins, you will need to debug on real device or emulator. Please see **Caution section** of [Run your Apache Cordova app on the Apache Ripple simulator](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ripple-simulator/).

Comment: Hi @Elvis Thanks for your answer. Actually, I'm debugging on real device. I could use the command in the JavaScript Console before on real device and debug it, but now I couldn't. It always shows "You are not currently attached to a supported page or app". I have no idea how to let it debug again.

Comment: Could you please use `adb devices` of [this link](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tips-and-workarounds-android-readme/) to check if your device is recognized by adb correctly.

Comment: Hi @Elvis. I've attached the picture on the question update. thanks for your help.